# Optimal way of finding a user in AD (Get-ADUser) based on different input

Tags: powershell, filter, split, active-directory

I'm looking for your thoughts on the optimal way of doing this.

The goal is simply to find a given user based on different possible inputs.

The possibilities are:

```
$input = "John,Smith"
$input = "John Smith"
$input = "John Smith(ext)"
$input = "Smith,John"
$input = "Smith John"
$input = "Smith John(ext)"
```

My working solution is :

```
if ($input -like "*(*" ) {
$input = $input -replace '\([^\)]+\)'
}

if ($input -like "*,*"){
$FullName = $input -split "," 
} 
elseif ($input -like "* *"){
$FullName = $input -split " "
} 


get-ADUser -Filter " ( ( (GivenName -like '$($FullName[0])*') -and (SurName -like '$($FullName[1])*') ) -or ( (SurName -like '$($FullName[0])*') -and (GivenName -like '$($FullName[1])*') ) ) "
```

So basically what is going on is :

-If the input contains parenthesis, remove them and what is between them.
-If the input contains a comma, split the string on that.
-If the input contains a space, split the string on that.
-Get-AdUser, filtering (GivenName and Surname) OR (Surname and GivenName)
 since I don't know which order they will be in.

It works fine as is but i'm always curious of finding the optimal way.

Do you have anything to suggest in this scenario? Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-LDAPFilter` and Ambiguous Name Resolution (`anr`):

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=John Doe)"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=Doe John)"
```

Just replace the comma with a space, and remove `"(ext)"`. Variable name `$input` is reserved, so it shouldn't be used:

```
$name = $name -replace ",", " "
$name = $name -replace "\(ext\)", ""
```

Or chaining the `-replace` operator:

```
$name = $name -replace ",", " " -replace "\(ext\)", ""
```

The search would be:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$name)"
```

Comment: Man this is good. I didn't know about anr, I used this solution but i kept my regex '\([^\)]+\)' since EXT is not guaranteed to be there. Thanks a LOT! :)

Comment: Ambiguous Name Resolution is described here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx

Comment: Couple things about this. 1. `$input` is a reserved variable name. Should use something else (yes I know you copied the OPs code). 2. you can chain -replace to keep it together on one line. `$userChoice = $userChoice -replace "," -replace "\(ext\)"`. Other then that I learned about anr today which is awesome.

Comment: That `$input` was nagging somewhere in my mind. Edited the post.

Comment: Thanks Matt, and yes input is just an example actual code is different good point though